# Pathless Routes are not configured in the react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I can't get pathless routes to work in react-router-dom. I took the code from the [tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#pathless-routes) on the official website, but it doesn't work, the error page still takes up the whole screen. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        errorElement: <Error />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Index /> },
          {
            path: "test",
            element: <Test />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

```
export default function Root() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In this file, the header and footer are just plain nondescript: we've included a `<Link to="path">`.